# Reusing layers for multiple stages in game

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a game with multiple levels (10 at the moment). I create a class for each level however this would be very, very tedious if more levels were to be added. My question is, how can I reuse a layer/class to have all levels of the game? The only difference for each level is the number of targets and the positions of the targets. Other than that, everything is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class called something like LevelLayer which implements all of the logic from one of the levels. Now, create a new class called Level1Layer which implements LevelLayer.

Now progressively move code that is specific to level1 from LevelLayer into Level1Layer until LevelLayer contains only code that is useful to all levels.

Now create a Level2Layer that inherits from LevelLayer. Note that suddenly most of the code for this level is already done and can be called via the methods on the base class (LevelLayer).

By doing this iteratively you end up with a base class (LevelLayer) which consolidates all of the code to do with being a generic level, with the specific code for each level being hived off in a class corresponding to the particular level.

Note that after a while you should have gotten to a point where code that both level1 and level2 needs is in LevelLayer, and code and data that *only* level1 needs is in Level1Layer and code that *only* level2 needs is in Level2Layer.

After a while you may find that all of the levels differ only by a particular data item (e.g. an int array containing the map). In this case you may want to create a class that takes this data item via the constructor (or deserializes it from a file, the path of which is supplied to the constructor) which implements LevelLayer.

At this point you will be able to spend most of your time editing the data files (the "level" files) rather than code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, what I need to do is create a base class where all the similar items (such as backgrounds, timer, stage label) will be in. Then create a class for each level that will contain items exclusively for them such as sprite position and animation?

Comment: That would be the normal approach, yes. Level layers should contain only code and data that distinguishes it from other levels. They should all inherit from a class that contains code that is useful to _all_ levels.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer. Do you know a good tutorial I can take a look at that shows this kind of implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what cocos2d is, but generally in this situation you'd want to create a generalized class called something like LevelMap and then make that class configurable. For each level in the game you'd created a new instance of that class and then either configure it in the code, or have the class read up some kind of configuration file (XML comes to mind) that defines what the level should look like.

For instance, you could pass a 2 dimensional array of GameObjects into your LevelMap's constructor and then let the LevelMap integrate those GameObjects into itself as the layout with the [0,0] position in the array being the upper left, and [array.xLength - 1, array.YLength - 1] being the lower right hand corner of the map. Or whatever convention you decided upon. It really doesn't matter that much as long as you pick something you're conceptually comfortable with and use it consistently.

You could do the same thing with XML by creating a structured document that lays out the level in the same way, telling the class where to put all the targets.